# Oracle EM Express not showing all options

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, oracle-enterprise-manager

Why I cant see options like 'create user' in Eterprise Manager. I have Oracle database 19C.
[image]

My EM Express is showing just the performance.

Bellow you can see in image that in 11g you can create tables and many other objects, just by using the EM Manager
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle deprecated the flash-based features of Enterprise Manager Express in 19c and replaced it with Jet-based technology. The new EM Express only shows performance metrics and contains no administrator functions for users, tablespaces, etc.

To revert back to the legacy flash-based EM Express you can use the steps given here: https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-revert-em-express-19c-to-flash-based-back-and-forth/, assuming you can still find a browser that will run Flash at all. Pretty much all browsers dropped their support for Adobe Flash technology almost two years ago, and Adobe has posted the following on their web site:

> Since Adobe no longer supports Flash Player after December 31, 2020
> and blocked Flash content from running in Flash Player beginning
> January 12, 2021, Adobe strongly recommends all users immediately
> uninstall Flash Player to help protect their systems.
>
> https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html